Ruby tally method: evaluating a hash with a key that is a date
In testing a rails method with Minitest, the following statement
Available.all.reload.pluck(:date).tally

returns the following hash
{Sat, 08 Jun 2024=>2, Tue, 25 Jun 2024=>12, Sun, 07 Jul 2024=>11}

The assertion that is being attempted is, after a transformation of data, to validate that the value for date key 2024-07-07 == 11.
The following, under the assumption that hash keys are instances of Time, returns false;
there is a date typing issue either in the statement or in the transformation of it to the console.
new_date = DateTime.new(2024,7,8,0,0,0).to_time
assert Available.all.reload.pluck(:date).tally.include?({new_date=>11})

How should this be written?

new_date = Date.parse("2024-07-07").  assert the hash has a matching key and the value for that key is 11

:date, DateTime, to_time – you have them all :) Date, Time and DateTime are all different classes, the latter being for historical dates. Check the classes of your hash keys (I assume Date instances) and compare to an instance of that class.


...under the assumption that hash keys are instances of Time

Based on the post those are not instances of Time which would be represented via inspect as "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%6N %z", instead these appear to be Date objects.
First thing I would recommend is that
Available.all.reload.pluck(:date).tally

Is equivalent to
Available.group(:date).count

This offloads the counting to the database and avoids the creation of an intermediate disposed Array
Secondly you can create a Date object using Date.new(2024,7,8).
Since we are using a Hash we can simply lookup the key and compare the value like so
Available.group(:date).count[Date.new(2024,7,8)] == 11

That being said if the target is always a single Date and the Hash is not necessary then something like this might be more efficient:
Available.where(date: Date.new(2024,7,8)).count == 11


useful way to appoach the issue from different sides.
